# non_field_errors, Invalid data. DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

when I post nested serializers in Postman it gives me following error

```
"profile": {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
}
```

but when I make the GET request it shows like that

```
    "email": null,
    "phone_number": null,
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "interestlist_set": [
            {
                "interest_list": [
                    2,
                    1
                ],
                "user": 1,
                "category": 1
            }
        ]
```

and I am posting as the same as above one more thing here interest_list is `ManyToManyField` it may be problem but I cannot solve this here is my model

**models.py**

```
class InterestName(TimeModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class InterestList(models.Model):
    interest_list = models.ManyToManyField(InterestName)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ListOfInterestCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interestlist_set = InterestListSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'interestlist_set',]

class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email', 'phone_number','profile']

def create(self, validated_data):
    profiles_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for profile_data in profiles_data:
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

here what I have tried so far I cannot make POST request in Postman how can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: since you didn't write custom **`create()`** method in `ProfileSerializer`, you may need to set the `interestlist_set` field to **`read_only=True`**

Comment: @JPG I wrote custom **create()** method in Profile like returned Profile.objects.create(**validated_data) then it did not work. Or should I add something to create() method like UserRegistrationSerializer.